# Convert a JSON (output of ADF activity) to a Dataframe for next activity

Tags: python, pandas, azure-data-factory

[image]

In Azure Data Factory, I have 2 Databricks notebooks.
The result of sample1 is a pandas dataframe. I use the below code for converting to JSON and send it to output.

```
processing_result = normalized_features.to_json(orient="index")
dbutils.notebook.exit(processing_result)
```

The output is:

```
 "runOutput": {
        "0": {
            "mean": 1.124771,
            "max": 6.0006,
            "min": 0.054,
            "std": 0.9000992859,
            "median": 0.8932,
            "L1": 112.4771,
            "MAD": 0.64386804,
            "percent_above_mean": 0.38,
            "variation_from_mean": 0.64386804
        }
    },
```

[image]

In the databricks sample2, I want to use the output of sample1 and I need to convert JSON to a dataframe. How can I do it?

| mean | max | min | std | median | L1 | MAD | percent_above_mean | variation_from_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.12 | 6.00 | 0.05 | 0.9 | 0.89 | 112 | 0.64 | 0.38 | 0.643 |

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with the below code and `json_normalize`

```
message_input = dbutils.widgets.get("input")
message_json = json.loads(message_input)
normalized_features = json_normalize(message_json['0'])
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.